# How can one ensure uptime running Sonatype Nexus on OpenShift Enterprise and show reason when fails?

Tags: nexus, sonatype, openshift-enterprise

Situation: I successfully log in to my cloud domain and application, cd into the nexus(version)/bin directory, where the executable lives, and type "./nexus start".
This works about 80% of the time, but I need it up 99.9% of the time. When it fails, I receive this message, only:

./nexus start
Starting Nexus OSS...
Failed to start Nexus OSS.

Additional info - I am running this on a DIY cartridge, which worked like a charm for about a week.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should set it up to [run as a service](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-service.html).

To figure why it fails you should have look at the log file, which can be found in sonatype-work/log/nexus.log

With details from there we can figure out more.